# Javascript, remove querystring from url and update url and browser history

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I have a url that can look like this:
[https://example.domain.no/modulsofa?f=1&kategori[0]=256](https://example.domain.no/modulsofa?f=1&kategori%5B0%5D=256)

My goal is to use javascript and remove the querystring from the URL. So that when you reload the page only https://example.domain.no/modulsofa is loaded.

What I'm doing now is this:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '', location.pathname);
```

This updates the URL and removes the querystring. But when I reload the page in Safari the old URL is loaded. How can I also make sure the new url is then one that is loaded when I reload the page?

Comment: Reload it yourself with the *correct* URL `window.location.href = 'whatever'`. Yet be aware that a user can always get the initial/correct URL in his/her logs if he/she wants to. If you have information in the URL that users shall not see, do not put it there to begin with.

Comment: I don't want to automatically reload the page. The whole idea here is to avoid that.

Comment: *Reload* as a browser functionality reloads the last loaded page and not the URL shown in the addressbar, which you can easily check by reloading after putting a totally different URL or emptying it. So your approach on changing the history state will not change the default browser reloading behaviour. You actually have to load that address for real first.

Comment: can I not push the new state to the history of the browser?

Comment: But the strange thing is that it works the other way around. I can use replaceState to add to the querystring, and if I reload after adding, the new url will be loaded. I don't understand why it won't work when I remove the querystring as well?